# How can I optimize this SQL Server System table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table with the following definition:

```
create table consTest(c1 integer null constraint consTest1 check(c1 < 100),
                      c2 integer not null constraint consTestU1 unique,
                      c3 integer not null,
                      c4 integer null,
                      constraint consTest2 check(c2 > c1),
                      constraint consTestU2 unique(c3))
```

My application has the following query to execute against the system tables to describe the constraint relationships of the columns in the table:

```
SELECT object_schema_name(t17.referencing_id), object_name(t17.referencing_id),
       coalesce(col_name(t17.referenced_id, t17.referenced_minor_id), NULL),
       t16.definition, t16.type
FROM   { oj sys.check_constraints t16 INNER JOIN  sys.sql_expression_dependencies t17 ON ( t17.referencing_id = t16.object_id )  }  
WHERE t17.referenced_id = object_id('consTest') AND
      t16.type = 'C' AND
      object_name(t17.referencing_id) = 'consTest2'
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC
```

I am seeing the occasional intermittent crash from SQL Server when executing this query. My question isn't about the crash but to see if anyone can recommend any optimizations I can make to my query.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I got an estimated subtree cost of .0100221 vs .0213887 with the original query:

```
SELECT object_schema_name(t17.referencing_id)
    , object_name(t17.referencing_id)
    , coalesce(col_name(t17.referenced_id, t17.referenced_minor_id), NULL)
    , t16.[definition]
    , t16.[type]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies t17
JOIN sys.check_constraints t16
    ON t17.referencing_id = t16.object_id
    AND t16.[type] = 'C'
    AND object_name(t17.referencing_id) = 'consTest2'
    AND t17.referenced_id = object_id('consTest');
GO
```